# Manage exceptions handling

Tags: python, excel, exception

I have class named *ExcelFile*, his job is to manage excel files (read, extract data, and differents things for the stack).

I want to implement a system for managing errors/exceptions.

For example, *ExcelFile* as a method *load()*, like a "setup"

```
def load(self):
        """
            Setup for excel file
            Load workbook, worksheet and others characteristics (data lines, header...)
            :return: Setup successfully or not
            :rtype: bool

            Current usage
            :Example:

            > excefile = ExcelFile('test.xls')
            > excefile.load()
                True
            > excefile.nb_rows()
                4
        """
        self.workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(self.url)
        self.sheet = self.workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        self.header_row_index = self.get_header_row_index()

        if self.header_row_index == None:  # If file doesn't have header (or not valid)
            return False

        self.header_fields = self.sheet.row_values(self.header_row_index)
        self.header_fields_col_ids = self.get_col_ids(self.header_fields)  # Mapping between header fields and col ids
        self.nb_rows = self.count_rows()
        self.row_start_data = self.header_row_index + self.HEADER_ROWS
        return True
```

As you can see, I can encounter  2 differents errors:

1. The file is not an excel file (raise xlrd.XLRDError)
2. The file has an invalid header (so I return False)

I want to implement a good management system of ExcelFile errors, because this class is used a lot in the stack.

This is my first idea for processing that :

Implement a standard exception

```
class ExcelFileException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, type=None):
        self.message = message
        self.type = type

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} : {} ({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.message, self.type)
```

Rewrite load method

```
def load(self):
    """
        Setup for excel file
        Load workbook, worksheet and others characteristics (data lines, header...)
        :return: Setup successfully or not
        :rtype: bool

        Current usage
        :Example:

        > excefile = ExcelFile('test.xls')
        > excefile.load()
            True
        > excefile.nb_rows()
            4
    """
    try:
        self.workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(self.url)
    except xlrd.XLRDError as e:
        raise ExcelFileException("Unsupported file type", e.__class__.__name__)

    self.sheet = self.workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    self.header_row_index = self.get_header_row_index()

    if self.header_row_index == None:  # If file doesn't have header (or not valid)
        raise ExcelFileException("Invalid or empty header")

    self.header_fields = self.sheet.row_values(self.header_row_index)
    self.header_fields_col_ids = self.get_col_ids(self.header_fields)  # Mapping between header fields and col ids
    self.nb_rows = self.count_rows()
    self.row_start_data = self.header_row_index + self.HEADER_ROWS
    return True
```

And this an example in a calling method, a big problem is I have to manage a dict named "report" with errors in french, for customers success and other.

```
    ...
def foo():
    ...
    file = ExcelFile(location)

    try:
        file.load()
    except ExcelFileException as e:
        log.warn(e.__str__())
        if e.type == 'XLRDError'
            self.report['errors'] = 'Long description of the error, in french (error is about invalid file type)'
        else:
            self.report['errors'] = 'Long description of the error, in french (error is about invalid header)'
...
```

What do you think about that ? Do you have a better way ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your exception to log the errors in your `dict`:

```
class ExcelFileException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, report, type=None):
        report['errors'].append(message)
        self.message = message
        self.type = type

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} : {} ({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.message, self.type)
```

When you will `raise` an `exception`:

```
raise ExcelFileException("Invalid or empty header", report)
```

The errors will be present in `self.dictionnary['errors']`

Comment: Thank you, but I have a condition : 1) The message in report must be in french and very explicit (for customer success and other members of the team)

Comment: And is not a good wat to do something like that : `raise ExcelFileException("Error message", "French description")`

Comment: If you have the error messages stored somewhere, you could use a `dict` with a description in french for the error message, something like `report['errors'].append(your_dict_with_french_descriptions[message])`

Answer (score 1):

Also the error can be fixed by installing missing a optional dependence Xlrd

`pip install Xlrd`

[More available python packages when working with excel](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Comment: I found a solution, but thank you I will look at this